# How to remove the delimiter at the end of a line in an Unix dat file?

Tags: file, unix

I have a dat file with data as follows:

```
030 »E  »EN  »20  »James            »
030 »E  »EN  »21  »John               »
```

The `»` is the delimiter in this. I need to remove the delimiter at the end of each line. Is this possible with Unix utilities? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Visakh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use a simple sed statement:

```
sed -i 's/>>\n/\n/g' *.dat
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is non-standard sed.  's/>>$//' is standard  (No need for g flag.)